# семейство Смитов или семейство Смит

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, будьте добры, семейство Смитов или семейство Смит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Семейство Смит.**

"Семейство Смитов" подразумевало бы только мужскую половину этого коллектива, но это крайне маловероятно.

Вообще подобные вещи регулируются правилами написания и склонения иностранных фамилий, но они крайне запутаны. Вот более или менее вразумительное описание, но, как сами авторы признают, совсем не полное.

> Примечание. Есть, однако, особые правила постановки таких фамилий в
>   одних случаях в склоняемой форме множественного числа, в других — в
>   несклоняемой форме. Правила эти, более относящиеся к синтаксису, чем к
>   морфологии, довольно подробно разработаны у Д. Э. Розенталя (см.:
>   Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке. М., 1989. С.
>   191—192, §149, п. 10). В соответствии с этими правилами рекомендуется:
>   с Томасом и Генрихом Маннами, но с Робертом и Кларой Шуман, у отца и
>   сына Ойстрахов, но у отца и дочери Гилельс. Здесь этот материал не
>   рассматривается.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/71-rubric-482

А вот что у самого Р. (здесь это §151, п. 10)

> .... 7)      при слове семья фамилия обычно ставится в форме
>   единственного числа, например: семья Оппенгейм, семья Гофман-сталь.

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm

Ну и заодно - общий обзор.
http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_8_familii/